# multiple working modes for motors

Tags: motor

with this sketch i can independently control 4 dc motors cw, ccw, and rotating each of them until the hall sensor related to it detects an magnetic field. what im trying to do now is to create a mode of operation in wich:just pressing button "nine", and first motor starts rotating until its hall sensor detects a magnetic field, after five seconds, the second motor acts the same and so on, ather the fourth motor, after 5 seconds, the first motor starts again. i spent like 5 hours trying but still cant do it. maybe for a pro its not that big deal cose its my first serious Arduino project.

```
#include <TLE94112.h>
#include <Tle94112Motor.h>
#include <IRremote.h>

#define unu 0x1
#define doi 0x2
#define trei 0x3
#define patru 0x4
#define sound 0x55
#define picture 0x54
#define feature 0x50
#define install 0x52
#define cinci 0x5
#define sase 0x6
#define sapte 0x7
#define opt 0x8
#define tv 0x63
#define av 0x56
#define e 0x60
#define eo 0x42

int RECV_PIN = 2;
int hallSensorPin1 = 3;
int hallSensorPin2 = 4;
int hallSensorPin3 = 5;
int hallSensorPin4 = 6;
int state1;
int oldState1 = 1;
int runMode1 = 0;
int state2;
int oldState2 = 1;
int runMode2 = 0;
int state3;
int oldState3 = 1;
int runMode3 = 0;
int state4;
int oldState4 = 1;
int runMode4 = 0;

Tle94112 controller = Tle94112();
Tle94112Motor motor1(controller);
Tle94112Motor motor2(controller);
Tle94112Motor motor3(controller);
Tle94112Motor motor4(controller);

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{ irrecv.enableIRIn();
  controller.begin();

  motor1.connect(motor1.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_HB1);
  motor1.connect(motor1.LOWSIDE, controller.TLE_HB2);
  motor1.setPwm(motor1.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_PWM2);
  motor1.setPwmFreq(motor1.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_FREQ200HZ);

  motor2.connect(motor2.LOWSIDE, controller.TLE_HB3);
  motor2.connect(motor2.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_HB4);
  motor2.setPwm(motor2.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_PWM2);
  motor2.setPwmFreq(motor2.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_FREQ200HZ);

  motor3.connect(motor3.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_HB5);
  motor3.connect(motor3.LOWSIDE, controller.TLE_HB6);
  motor3.setPwm(motor3.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_PWM2);
  motor3.setPwmFreq(motor3.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_FREQ200HZ);

  motor4.connect(motor4.LOWSIDE, controller.TLE_HB7);
  motor4.connect(motor4.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_HB8);
  motor4.setPwm(motor4.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_PWM2);
  motor4.setPwmFreq(motor4.HIGHSIDE, controller.TLE_FREQ200HZ);

  motor1.begin();
  motor2.begin();
  motor3.begin();
  motor4.begin();
}
void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume();

    if (results.value == unu || results.value == 0x801 || results.value == 0x2049) {
      motor1.start(63);
      runMode1 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == cinci || results.value == 0x805 || results.value == 0x2053) {
      motor1.start(-63);
      runMode1 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == tv || results.value == 0x63 || results.value == 0x2111 || results.value == 0x83F || results.value == 0x3F) {
      motor1.coast();
      runMode1 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == sound || results.value == 0x55 || results.value == 0x2103 || results.value == 0x837 || results.value == 0x37) {
      motor1.start(63);
      runMode1 = 1;
    }
    if (results.value == doi || results.value == 0x802 || results.value == 0x2050) {
      motor2.start(63);
      runMode2 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == sase || results.value == 0x806 || results.value == 0x2054) {
      motor2.start(-63);
      runMode2 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == av || results.value == 0x56 || results.value == 0x2104 || results.value == 0x838 || results.value == 0x38) {
      motor2.coast();
      runMode2 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == picture || results.value == 0x54 || results.value == 0x2102 || results.value == 0x836 || results.value == 0x36) {
      motor2.start(63);
      runMode2 = 1;
    }
    if (results.value == trei || results.value == 0x803 || results.value == 0x2051) {
      motor3.start(63);
      runMode3 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == sapte || results.value == 0x807 || results.value == 0x2055) {
      motor3.start(-63);
      runMode3 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == e || results.value == 0x60 || results.value == 0x2108 || results.value == 0x83C || results.value == 0x3C) {
      motor3.coast();
      runMode3 = 0;
    }
   if(results.value==feature||results.value==0x50||results.value==0x2098||results.value==0x832||results.value==0x32){
      motor3.start(63);
      runMode3 = 1;
    }
    if (results.value == patru || results.value == 0x804 || results.value == 0x2052) {
      motor4.start(63);
      runMode4 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == opt || results.value == 0x808 || results.value == 0x2056) {
      motor4.start(-63);
      runMode4 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == eo || results.value == 0x42 || results.value == 0x2090 || results.value == 0x82A || results.value == 0x2A) {
      motor4.coast();
      runMode4 = 0;
    }
    if (results.value == install || results.value == 0x52 || results.value == 0x2100 || results.value == 0x834 || results.value == 0x34) {
      motor4.start(63);
      runMode4 = 1;
    }
  }
  state1 = digitalRead(hallSensorPin1);


  if (state1 == HIGH) {
    oldState1 = 1;
  }
  if (state1 == LOW && oldState1 == 1 && runMode1 == 1) {
    motor1.coast();
    oldState1 = 0;
  }
state2 = digitalRead(hallSensorPin2);

  if (state2 == HIGH) {
    oldState2 = 1;
  }
  if (state2 == LOW && oldState2 == 1 && runMode2 == 1) {
    motor2.coast();
    oldState2 = 0;
  }

  state3 = digitalRead(hallSensorPin3);
  
  if (state3 == HIGH) {
    oldState3 = 1;
  }
  if (state3 == LOW && oldState3 == 1 && runMode3 == 1) {
    motor3.coast();
    oldState3 = 0;
  }
  state4 = digitalRead(hallSensorPin4);
  
  if (state4 == HIGH) {
    oldState4 = 1;
  }
  if (state4 == LOW && oldState4 == 1 && runMode4 == 1) {
    motor4.coast();
    oldState4 = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: what problem are you having? ... unable to detect `9` being pressed? ... something else? ... we are not going to spend time guessing what you are observing

Comment: Timed things are normally done with the `millis()` or `micros()` function, like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example. There are tons of tutorials out there about that. For writing code for multiple modes, you should look into the structure of an FSM (Finite State Machine). That is a simple but powerful concept, also often described on the web. I have also once written a longer answer about FSMs [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/63488/wanted-to-control-2-servos-with-serial-read), with diagrams and all. Understanding that concept will really help you